# QuantLib (Python) ZeroCouponBond. Appropriate yield curve

Tags: quantlib

I want to find the NPV of a ZeroCouponBond in Quantlib. I am adapting the code from https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/32539 for FixedRateBonds. The code below runs (82.03), but I am not sure which compoundingFrequency to set for the term structure in the case of a zero coupon bond. 
The only thing that makes sense to me is to set the discount factors to annual compouding. Or is there anything particular about using ZeroCouponBond together with ZeroCurve that I am overlooking?

```
    from QuantLib import *

    # Construct yield curve
    calc_date = Date(1, 1, 2017)
    Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calc_date

    spot_dates = [Date(1,1,2017), Date(1,1,2018), Date(1,1,2027)]
    spot_rates = [0.04, 0.04, 0.04]

    day_count = SimpleDayCounter()
    calendar = NullCalendar()
    interpolation = Linear()
    compounding = Compounded
    compounding_frequency = Annual
    spot_curve = ZeroCurve(spot_dates, spot_rates, day_count, calendar,
                           interpolation, compounding,
                           compounding_frequency)

    spot_curve_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(spot_curve)

    # Construct bond schedule
    issue_date = Date(1, 1, 2017)
    maturity_date = Date(1, 1, 2022)

    settlement_days = 0
    face_value = 100

    bond = ZeroCouponBond(settlement_days,
                          # calendar
                          calendar,
                          # faceamout
                          face_value,
                          # maturity_date
                          maturity_date,
                          # paymentconvention
                          Following,
                          # redemption
                          face_value,
                          # issue date
                          issue_date
                          )

    # Set Valuation engine
    bond_engine = DiscountingBondEngine(spot_curve_handle)
    bond.setPricingEngine(bond_engine)

    # Calculate present value
    value = bond.NPV()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frequency doesn't depend on the fact that the bond is a zero-coupon bond; it depends on how the rates you're using were calculated or quoted.  If the 4% was calculated or quoted as an annually compounded rate, that's what you should use; otherwise, you'll have to determine what "4%" means.